# Why can't I store modification time in milliseconds in a variable in Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to return an array of equivalent files in which the inner array contains the last modified file as the 0th index. I was able to get it to work by storing the mtime property, but I'm curious why I couldn't store the value of the mtimeMs property on the fileStats object in the array since its data type is number.

My code is below

```
var walk = require('walk'), fs = require('fs'), walker;
var path = require('path');
// console.log(walk.walk);

  walker = walk.walk(path.join(__dirname, "/testAll"));

  let fileData = {};
  let results = [];

walker.on('file', function (root, fileStats, next) {
  // console.log('root is: ', root, 'fileStats is: ', fileStats, 'next is: ', next);
  fs.readFile(path.join(root, fileStats.name), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (fileData[data]) {
      fileData[data][1] < fileStats.mtimeMS ? 
        results.push([fileStats.name, fileData[data][0]]) : 
        results.push([fileData[data][0], fileStats.name])
    } else {
      fileData[data] = [fileStats.name, fileStats.mtimeMS]; //undefined is added as the 1st index of this array
    }
    next();
  });
});

walker.on('end', () => {
  console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I couldn't store the value of the mtimeMs variable"*?

Comment: My system doesn't seem to return `*Ms` values for stat, but perhaps this should be `mtimeMs` (lowercase S).

Comment: You're correct, but I only misspelled it in the question so the problem still remains. @ExplosionPills

Comment: @Tomalak I meant the mtimeMs property on the object referenced by fileStats.